# Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Используется на сайте вот такой код для плавного скролла по якорю

```
$('a[href*="#"]')
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(this).closest('ul').hasClass('story-anchors')) {

      var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        countWindows = $(this).attr("data-windowCount");

      clickAnchor(this, 0, 0, 1200, 0, windowHeight, countWindows);

    } else if ($(this).closest('ul').hasClass('anchors-list')) {
      var navHeight = $('.anchors-list').outerHeight() - 2;
      clickAnchor(this, navHeight, 1, 500, 1, 0, 0);
    } else {
      clickAnchor(this, 0, 1, 500, 1, 0, 0);
    }
  });

function clickAnchor(ob, heightNav, attrHeaderHeight, speed, attrTop, windowHeight, countWindows) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var headerHeight = $('.header').height();

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: (windowHeight * countWindows) + ($($.attr(ob, 'href')).offset().top * attrTop) - (headerHeight * attrHeaderHeight) - heightNav
  }, speed);
}
```

на одной из страниц идет ссылка на якорь, который находится на другой странице.
При клике на такую ссылку в консоли выбивает:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined*

Функция в данном случае использует последний else.

Это как-то можно пофиксить?

Answer (score 0):

```
function clickAnchor(ob, heightNav, attrHeaderHeight, speed, attrTop, windowHeight, countWindows) {

  // откуда здесь берется объект event?
  //event.preventDefault();
  var headerHeight = $('.header').height();

  // проверьте, что количество элементов - один, и jQuery может вычислить его положение
  console.log($.attr(ob, 'href'), $($.attr(ob, 'href')).length, $($.attr(ob, 'href')).offset());  
  if ($($.attr(ob, 'href')).offset()) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: (windowHeight * countWindows) + ($($.attr(ob, 'href')).offset().top * attrTop) - (headerHeight * attrHeaderHeight) - heightNav
    }, speed);
  }
}
```

Comment: на `.length > 0` можно не проверять

Answer (score 0):

В общем, вынес я объект event во внешнюю функцию - так вроде бы все работает

```
$('a[href*="#"]')
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]').on('click', function(event) {

    if ($(this).closest('ul').hasClass('story-anchors')) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        countWindows = $(this).attr("data-windowCount");

      clickAnchor(this, 0, 0, 1200, 0, windowHeight, countWindows);

    } else if ($(this).closest('ul').hasClass('anchors-list')) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var navHeight = $('.anchors-list').outerHeight() - 2;
      clickAnchor(this, navHeight, 1, 500, 1, 0, 0);
    } else {
      clickAnchor(this, 0, 1, 500, 1, 0, 0);
    }
  });

function clickAnchor(ob, heightNav, attrHeaderHeight, speed, attrTop, windowHeight, countWindows) {

  var headerHeight = $('.header').height();

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: (windowHeight * countWindows) + ($($.attr(ob, 'href')).offset().top * attrTop) - (headerHeight * attrHeaderHeight) - heightNav
  }, speed);
}
```

Comment: здесь слово "вроде бы" - ключевое. Вы не починили то, что не работало.